# How to get id of an element inside row and column?

Tags: laravel

I have day and time table.
i have shown day and time in a loop like this.
[image: Futsal Reservation System]
I want to assign the id of AV (Green) from both day and time table.
For example : I want to assign id for AV located at Monday 10-11 AM. I want to assign both monday id and 10-11 Am id in that data.

My code looks like this

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm book-table">
                         <tbody>
                           <tr class="days">
                             <th>
                              Days/time
                             </th>
                             @foreach($times as $time)
                            <td>{{$time->time}} {{$time->shift}}</td>
                             @endforeach
                           </tr>
                           @foreach($days as $day)
                           <tr> 

                             <th>{{$day->day}}</th>
                           <td class="av hello" data-id="{{$day->id}}">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td>
                             <td class="av">AV</td> 
                          </tr>
                            @endforeach
                         </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give date and time ID separately you can do this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm book-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="days">
      <th>Days/time</th>
      @foreach($times as $time)
      <td>{{ $time->time }} {{ $time->shift }}</td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
    @foreach($days as $day)

    <tr>
      <th>{{ $day->day }}</th>
      @foreach($times as $time)
      <td class="av hello" data-day_id="{{ $day->id }}" data-time_id="{{ $time->id }}">AV</td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>

    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or if you want to give one id for each AV you can do:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm book-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="days">
      <th>Days/time</th>
      @foreach($times as $time)
      <td>{{ $time->time }} {{ $time->shift }}</td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
    @foreach($days as $day)

    <tr>
      <th>{{ $day->day }}</th>
      @foreach($times as $time)
        <td class="av hello" data-id="{{ $day->id }}_{{ $time->id }}">AV</td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>

    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm book-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="days">
        <th>
            Days/time
        </th>
        @foreach($times as $time)
        <td>{{$time->time}} {{$time->shift}}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    @foreach($days as $day)
    <tr>
        <th>{{$day->day}}</th>
        @foreach($times as $time)
        <td class="av hello" data-id="{{$day->id}}_{{$time->time}}">AV</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since time ranges are already fixed, you don't really need to use foreach inside foreach

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm book-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="days">
         <th>
            Days/time
         </th>
         @foreach($times as $time)
         <td>{{$time->time}} {{$time->shift}}</td>
         @endforeach
      </tr>
      @foreach($days as $day)
      <tr>
         <th>{{$day->day}}</th>
         <td class="av hello" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[0]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[1]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[2]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[3]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[4]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[5]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[6]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[7]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[8]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[9]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[10]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[11]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[12]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[13]->time}}">AV</td>
         <td class="av" data-id="{{$day->id}}-{{$times[14]->time}}">AV</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```